# How to run tests before commit in create react app?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app

How to run jest in create react app before commit? I have found couple articles but they are too complicated , without explaining what to do step by step.  Could you please explain me how to make it work

Comment: Well commiting to git and `create-react-app` aren't really related to each other. But basically, you wanna use a git hook. If you look in `.git/hooks` you'll see example ones. The `pre-commit` one is the one you wanna add your test command to, and check the return value of the test command. If it's a fail, then you'll wanna call `exit` in your pre-commit hook to cancel the commit. There's also a tool called `husky` which can make defining git hooks a lot easier, and there's documentation for it and articles on how to add it to your project. Maybe use that to keep things simple

Answer (score 12):

You need to use [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) package. Here is basic configuration (put it in `package.json`). It adds `pre-commit` hook to your git configuration.

```
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "CI=true npm run test",
  }
}
```

You can also consider using [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) to lint files which you commit. You can see full configuration [here](https://github.com/morewings/react-template).

Comment: Installed Husky, added this to package.json, hook still doesn't work. Something is missing here.

Comment: New version of husky uses another way of configuration, please refer to documentation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can utilise some npm packages for this.

So, this is not a direct solution but you can include as many things you want instead of using git commands, shells and yml files

Install package **Pre-Commit** and install **git-cz** from npm. Using these you can make use of pre-commit and commit in package.json and desired things to them.

Now you can make use of these packages in your packages.json like below

`{
    "start": "node index.js",
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
    "commit": "git-cz",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx",
}`

For example you want to run test cases then **pre-commit: npm run test && lint-staged**

Because in our project we needed to update documents, checking style-lint, eslint and test cases, so we were using these combination.

But you should not commit directly using **git commit -m "message"** but with **npm run commit.**

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score -1):

To do **locally** you can just write a script which first runs the tests and pipes the exit code and decides whether to really push or not based on the exit code.

By default `npm test` runs in interactive mode

To exit after running the tests use CI=true

i.e. `CI=true npm test`

Comment: OP asks about running tests locally, not on CI

Comment: The reason I added gitlab answer was because one of the tags of this question has gitlab in it.

Comment: Everybody makes mistakes, comrade. Peace.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:
`npm install --save-dev pre-commit`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit

Then, in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "CI=true react-scripts test", //<-- update
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  }
```

Adding `CI=true` runs all tests without making it interactive

Finally,

```
"devDependencies": {
    "pre-commit": "test"
  }
```

Comment: how this line works!, "pre-commit": "test" , instead of "test" it should be the module version